# How can I call the methods in a class to a Game class?

Tags: java, methods, system.out

So what I need is:

- When the user enters number 1 from the `Game` class it should run the `methodOne` in the `Method` class and prints out the values.

I'm having difficulties in printing the values.
If someone know how to do this please help, I really appreciate it.

Here is the code for `Methods` with its `method1` and the `Game` class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Method {
    private static int Str, Dex, Con, Int, Wis, Cha;
    static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static Integer[] methodOne() {
        List<Integer> stats = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        // Entering an integer by the user,
        // checking the validity and exiting
        // from the game if invalid
        System.out.print("Enter Str : ");
        Str = sc.nextInt();
        while (Str < 0) {
            System.err.println("Invalid Input!!");
            Str = sc.nextInt();
        }

        // Entering an integer by the user,
        // checking the validity and exiting
        // from the game if invalid
        System.out.print("Enter Dex : ");
        Dex = sc.nextInt();
        while (Dex < 0) {
            System.err.println("Invalid Input!!");
            Dex = sc.nextInt();
        }

        // Entering an integer by the user,
        // checking the validity and exiting
        // from the game if invalid
        System.out.print("Enter Con : ");
        Con = sc.nextInt();
        while (Con < 0) {
            System.err.println("Invalid Input!!");
            Con = sc.nextInt();
        }

        // Entering an integer by the user,
        // checking the validity and exiting
        // from the game if invalid
        System.out.print("Enter Int : "); 
        Int = sc.nextInt();
        while (Int < 0) {
            System.err.println("Invalid Input!!");
            Int = sc.nextInt();
        }

        // Entering an integer by the user,
        // checking the validity and exiting
        // from the game if invalid
        System.out.print("Enter Wis : ");
        Wis = sc.nextInt();
        while (Wis < 0) {
            System.err.println("Invalid Input!!");
            Wis = sc.nextInt();
        }

        // Entering an integer by the user,
        // checking the validity and exiting
        // from the game if invalid
        System.out.print("Enter Cha : ");
        Cha = sc.nextInt();
        while (Cha < 0) {
            System.err.println("Invalid Input!!");
            Cha = sc.nextInt();
        }

        Integer statsValue[] = stats.toArray(new Integer[0]);
        return statsValue;
    }
}
```

As you can see in `methodTwo`, 4 dice are rolled and the lowest value is suspended.

I need to assign these rolled amounts to the 6 variables and store them for later use. No need to print the values. Sorry for the trouble caused in the previous question about printing.

```
public static int methodTwo() {
    int dice1 = (int) (Math.random() * 1000 % 6 + 1);
    int dice2 = (int) (Math.random() * 1000 % 6 + 1);
    int dice3 = (int) (Math.random() * 1000 % 6 + 1);
    int dice4 = (int) (Math.random() * 1000 % 6 + 1);
    int total;
    // finding the lowest amount
    if (dice1 < dice2 && dice1 < dice3 && dice1 < dice4) {
        total = dice2 + dice3 + dice4;
    } else if (dice2 < dice3 && dice2 < dice4) {
        total = dice1 + dice3 + dice4;
    } else if (dice3 < dice4) {
        total = dice1 + dice2 + dice4;
    } else {
        total = dice1 + dice2 + dice3;
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: You probably have the difficulty in the area in method1. Where is method1?

Comment: I don't see anywhere that you printing any thing! and where is the methodTwo definition?

Comment: ok.. and i didn't put the methodTwo part because first i need to fix the problems in methodOne.

Comment: The thing is you are not adding the results nowhere nor printing them...

Comment: Unrelated, but it's nice to follow Java naming conventions-makes it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `Method2`, I would suggest using an array of four integers, representing the four dice rolls. Then, sum it up. Find the smallest roll using a loop and subtract the sum from it.

```
    final int DICES = 4;
    int[] diceroll = new int[DICES];
    diceroll[0] = (int) (Math.random() * 1000 % 6 + 1);
    diceroll[1] = (int) (Math.random() * 1000 % 6 + 1);
    diceroll[2] = (int) (Math.random() * 1000 % 6 + 1);
    diceroll[3] = (int) (Math.random() * 1000 % 6 + 1);
    int total = diceroll[0] + diceroll[1] + diceroll[2] + diceroll[3];
    System.out.printf("%d %d %d %d\n", diceroll[0], diceroll[1], diceroll[2], diceroll[3]);

    // finding the lowest amount
    int min = diceroll[0];
    for (int k = 0; k < DICES; k++) {
        if (diceroll[k] < min)
            min = diceroll[k];
    }
    total -= min;
```

Comment: But how can i assign the values to the variables... should it be in the main method?

Comment: Which values. I don't think they should be in main. Method2 handles the dice roll.

Comment: The total of the dices (removing the minimum value) must be assigned to the six variables. (Str,Dex,Con,Int,Wis,Cha). Like in the first one instead of the user entering the values we are now rolling dices and assigning those values.

Comment: Sure. Just remember that the rolled dices should be stored in an array to find lowest amount.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there are some important issues with your code, that renders your ArrayList *empty*, meaning that the results can't be correctly printed as expected.

- You need to add the six inputted variables to `stats`.
- Are you sure you will only input six variables? If so, an ArrayList is not required, you can just use `int[6] statsValue`.
- `List<Integer> stats = new ArrayList<Integer>();`, that should be `ArrayList<Integer>`

You forgot to print the Integer ArrayList converted to array. To do that, you can either:

- Before returning StatsValue, **print** ArrayList `stats`.
- In the game, assign an `int[]` to the `return` value of Method1, then use a loop to print each integer individually.

Here is the revised code for `Integer[] method1` assuming you still use the ArrayList.

```
public static Integer[] methodOne() {
    ArrayList<Integer> stats = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    // Entering an integer by the user,
    // checking the validity and exiting
    // from the game if invalid
    System.out.print("Enter Str : "); 
    Str = sc.nextInt();
    while (Str < 0) {
        System.err.println("Invalid Input!!");
        Str = sc.nextInt();
    }
    stats.add(Str); // Add inputs to ArrayList stats

    System.out.print("Enter Dex : ");
    Dex = sc.nextInt();
    while (Dex < 0) {
        System.err.println("Invalid Input!!");
        Dex = sc.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.print("Enter Con : "); 
    stats.add(Dex);         

    Con = sc.nextInt();
    while (Con < 0) {
        System.err.println("Invalid Input!!");
        Con = sc.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.print("Enter Int : ");
    stats.add(Con);                 

    Int = sc.nextInt();
    while (Int < 0) {
        System.err.println("Invalid Input!!");
        Int = sc.nextInt();
    }
    stats.add(Int);
    System.out.print("Enter Wis : "); 

    Wis = sc.nextInt();
    while (Wis < 0) {
        System.err.println("Invalid Input!!");
        Wis = sc.nextInt();
    }
    stats.add(Wis);
    System.out.print("Enter Cha : "); 

    Cha = sc.nextInt();
    while (Cha < 0) {
        System.err.println("Invalid Input!!");
        Cha = sc.nextInt();
    }
    stats.add(Cha);

    System.out.println(stats); // You can print elements of an Arraylist directly
    Integer statsValue[] = stats.toArray(new Integer[0]);
    return statsValue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help and is it ok if u can show me how to  deal with second method as well

Comment: I'll edit my code cuz it'll be easier to understand.

Comment: Thanx. What are you planning to do for Method2, Method3, Method4?

Comment: Roll 4d6 and discard the lowest value and if the attribute is 16 or higher, add the value of an additional 1d6. This is what i have to do in method 3 .

Comment: Thanks. I also want to clarify how does each of the six attributes do in your game?

Comment: I forgot the important detail, which is that this game is based on the Dungeons and Dragons game. Not exactly the game but quite similar to it, so the six variables are from that game.